# How to use the credentials returned by ExAws.STS.assume_role

Tags: amazon-web-services, elixir

assume_role doc: https://hexdocs.pm/ex_aws_sts/ExAws.STS-function-assume_role.html

I need to programmatically assume a role. The credentials works if I manually add it to configuration

```elixir
config :ex_aws,
  json_codec: Jason,
  access_key_id: {:system, "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"},
  secret_access_key: {:system, "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"}
  session_token: {:system, "AWS_SESSION_TOKEN"}
```

How do I do it at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can pass config to `ExAws.request()`, This snippet taken from [`assume_role_credentials_adapter.ex`](https://github.com/ex-aws/ex_aws_sts/blob/10a909917269df737f36e6b0145800c023ca5da3/lib/ex_aws/sts/auth_cache/assume_role_credentials_adapter.ex#L31-L48):

```
assume_role_request =
  ExAws.STS.assume_role(auth.role_arn, role_session_name, assume_role_options)

assume_role_config = ExAws.Config.new(:sts, source_profile_auth)

with {:ok, result} <- ExAws.request(assume_role_request, assume_role_config) do
  %{
    access_key_id: result.body.access_key_id,
    secret_access_key: result.body.secret_access_key,
    security_token: result.body.session_token,
    role_arn: auth.role_arn,
    role_session_name: role_session_name,
    source_profile: auth.source_profile
  }
```